# Controller giving an error

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, force.com

My code below is giving me an error- `System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Account.mfField__c` I'm not clear on why I'm getting this error...

Help?

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="myObjectController">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Archived Records">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!relatedRecords}" var="item">
                <apex:column value="{!item.name}"/> 
            </apex:pageBlockTable> 
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public with sharing class myObjectController {

    Account current;
    List<Account> relatedRecords{get;set;}

    public myObjectController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
       this.current = (Account )controller.getRecord();       
       this.relatedRecords = [select id, name, mfField__c from  Account  where mfField__c = :this.current.mfField__c];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Account being returned by the Standard Controller doesn't have the mfField__c set on it and you're using it in your where clause.

Use the addFields method on your controller constructor to set the field on the record.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/apex_pages_standardcontroller.htm

Comment: it does have the field set though.... there is a value for the field

Comment: this.current.mfField__c ?

Comment: Yea.... it has a value already

Comment: Are you saying that on the basis of a System.debug somewhere ? The field may have a value, but since its not being referenced in VF, the field value will not get explicitly initialised until you reference it or invoke the addFields method.

Answer (score 1):

By default, a Visualforce page and its associated controller will only load the fields it sees referenced on the page. Your SOQL statement is referencing a field that is not used on the page. The easiest way to fix that is to reference the field on the page and set the `rendered` flag to false.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="myObjectController">
<apex:form >
    <apex:inputHidden  value="{!Account.mfField__c}"/>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Archived Records">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!relatedRecords}" var="item">
            <apex:column value="{!item.name}"/> 
        </apex:pageBlockTable> 
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

and controller as

```
public with sharing class myObjectController {

Account current;
List<Account> relatedRecords{get;set;}

public myObjectController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
   this.current = (Account )controller.getRecord();       
   this.relatedRecords = [select id, name, mfField__c from  Account  where mfField__c = :current.mfField__c];
}
```

}